# Google Cloud Identity API - missing device fields/data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-identity

and thank you beforehand for taking the time to check out my question.

While using Cloud Identity API to query for managed devices (Windows, Mac) details from our Google Workspace, I am able to query successfully by the "device ID" assigned by google, however, the "hostname" field is not included in the response.

THis is an example of the response that I get.

```
{'devices':
    [{'name': 'devices/xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'createTime': '9999-99-99T20:11:31.680Z',
      'lastSyncTime': '9999-99-99T15:01:51.922Z', 
      'ownerType': 'Company Owned',
      'model': 'Windows',
      'osVersion': 'Win10',
      'deviceType': 'Windows',
      'serialNumber': '737dh39he8d3978'}]
}
```

When looking at any device through Workspace, I can see similar details including the hostname. Any tip or idea is appreciated.
[sample image of device details in workspace gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMsJA.png)

Comment: The API's [Device](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/devices#resource:-device)  resource does not include a "hostname". What API endpoint are you calling? And which URL are you visitng when using the UI?

Comment: The UI URL looks like this:
https://admin.google.com/ac/devices/details/86134fa4-90b2-5098-6384-d19d0775r9gg/information?uid=7dhdhw7hd3h83d&dt=4

This is the API endpoint:
https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/